# Excel: is there a way to replace a peculiar part of a cell string?

Tags: excel, string, findandmodify

I have an excel export with a column containing staff previous training sessions in a string.
Example:
`First Name|Last Name|Training title|January 2018 to February 2018`

Due to non obligatory form fields from which data was collected, many strings have no end month value, like this `January 2018 to`
I'm trying to find a formula to find all strings **ending** with `to` (hence followed by nothing else) and delete this orphaned part of the string so it will look like `January 2018`.

Find and replace is useless as it also replaces the value when there's an end month/year. Substitute seems like a good way to go but I've failed trying to find the proper structure to the formula.

Comment: You could use find() if you make surte it starts its search with only the last two characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test whether it ends in `to` with right, and if so then use left to omit it:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,2) = "to",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),A1)
```

Comment: With some adaptations for my french version of Excel this worked flawlessly. Thank you Scott.
In case a fellow baguette comes around here with the same issue:
`=SI(DROITE(A1;2)="to";GAUCHE(A1;NBCAR(A1)-2);A1)`

Answer (score 0):

This is with VBA. Dont forget to check for extra spaces at the end. if there are any use TRIM.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Remove()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

    'Change Sheet if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To Lastrow

            If Right(.Range("A" & i).Value, 2) = "to" Then
                .Range("A" & i).Value = Left(.Range("A" & i).Value, Len(.Range("A" & i).Value) - 3)
            End If
        Next i


    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try this as well. My VBA skills need some training :)